# How to plot several columns on the same line chart in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

my `data` is

```
year female male unknown
1929   0     50     0
1930   2     70     7
1931   0     400    1
1932  20     40     15
1933  25     120    0
```

I need to create a simple line chart with 3 lines where I can see gender changes over years.

I have tried something like

```
data <- melt(data,  id.vars = 'year', variable.name = 'Gender')

ggplot(data, aes(year, value)) + geom_line(aes(colour = Gender))
```

but it shows me an empty chart and a comment

> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to
> adjust the group aesthetic?

1. How can I create a chart where I will have three lines, one for each gender?
2. Also, my date is bigger than this one, it contains 92 years so when I plot something, I get a huge mess of years on the x-axis

[image]

Is there a way to somehow fix it?

Comment: try adding `group = Gender` in the aes() of the initial ggplot line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tidyverse`, we pivot to 'long' format, specify the `group` and `color` with the column name 'name' column (default naming)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
data %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -year) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value, group = name, color = name)) + 
      geom_line()
```

[image]

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(year = 1929:1933, female = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 20L, 
25L), male = c(50L, 70L, 400L, 40L, 120L), unknown = c(0L, 7L, 
1L, 15L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: key difference from OP's attempt is that year doesn't turn into a factor.  Is this a difference between `melt` and `pivot_longer` ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker for me, the `year` remains the same type 'int' in `melt` using the data I used

Comment: then maybe OP started with a factor by accident?

Comment: It is possible.  Also, the R version may be a factor in that (`stringsAsFactors` in 4.0)

Comment: This worked really well with visualization! Thank you! The only problem is the mess with years on the x-axis when I am using my original data with 92 years, just like on the example from my question. Are there any ways to print there not all of the years, for example, with a distance of 20 years? Thank you!

Comment: make sure you convert your years back to numeric, e.g. I think `data$year <- levels(data$year)[data$year]` should work?

Comment: @BenBolker I fixed it with scale_x_discrete(). Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
matplot(data$year,data[,-1], type="l")
```

?